# js regex negate a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I mean if I have a string `abc`, `ab` should be matched but if I have a string `acd`, `a` should not be matched

I use `[^(ab)]` but doesn`t work.

I want `'abc'.match(/ regex /)` to output `c` and `'acd'.match(/ regex /)` to output `acd`

Comment: I mean if I have a string abc, ab should be matched but if I have a string acd, a should not be matched

Comment: negative lookahead does not work in JS

Comment: I`ve edited my details. Please check

Comment: A shot in the dark: [`(?:(?=ab)ab|(?!ab)(?!))`](https://regex101.com/r/kK7dO4/1).

Comment: Are these `a`, `b`, `c` just symbols, or placeholders of longer expressions?

Comment: Dude, I think its easy, I want to extract all characters from a string, but not the group `ab` if `a` is single, then is fine. But I need to use [^ab]

Comment: Please check my answer. I think I finally got what you mean. Note that a negated character class matches every symbol that is not specified in that class. Thus, all characters other than `a`s, `b`s and `)`s and `(`s are matched with `[^(abc)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in `String#replace`:

```
var result = input.replace(/\ba[^c]/, '');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS0hB9/4)

This will replace `a` if is followed by anything but `c` by empty string.

This will replace:

```
abc => c
acd => acd
```

Answer (score 0):

`^(?!.*ab).+$` meaning string must not contain `ab` - Or `^(?=.*ab).+$` meaning string must include `ab`

Use http://regexr.com/ to help you

Comment: dude are you seriously? `'abc'.match(/^(?!.*ab).+$/)` is null

Comment: Try `^(?=.*ab).+$` for a match

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just removing all `ab` from the string:

```
str.replace(/ab/gi, '')
```

And then just match what remains.

```js
var re = /ab/gi; 
var str = 'abc\nacd\nabcb';
var result = str.replace(re, '').match(/[a-z]+/gi);
alert(result);
```

Comment: But it will only match `c` in `abcb`

Comment: Ok, so pure regex is not enough.  I updated the solution.